# Sort Array Alphabetically (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to sort an array alphabetically (with a few parallel arrays) but I don't know what to do nor can I find anything on sorting an array alphabetically. I know some basics on sorting, but I have no idea how to sort a string array in alphabetical order.

EDIT: I'm working with four parallel arrays: first name, last name, id, and grade. I'm trying to sort by last name, which is a string. I know how to swap all of the info, just need to know how to compare alphabetically.

Comment: I'm trying to do [a thing], but I have no idea.  That's more of a _work order_ than a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below . .

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std ;

struct Student
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    float grade ;
    string id ;

};

bool byLastName(Student b ,Student a)
{
  if( strcmp(a.lastName.c_str() , b.lastName.c_str()) == 1 )
    return true ;
  return false ;
}


int main()
{
    Student them [] = {
        {"Sudipto" , "Roy" , 3.5 , "A-51"},
        {"Potter" , "Zam" , 4.5 , "X-420"},
    };

    int themCount = sizeof (them) / sizeof (Student) ;

    sort(them , them + themCount  , byLastName);

    for ( auto a : them )
        cout << a.lastName <<endl ;


    return 0;
}
```